# Android suddenly refuses to play ANY videos in any app on my galaxy tab s2

Tags: samsung, video

Is there any way to fix this without restarting?

Attempting to play any video in any app on my Galaxy Tab S2 will cause the video tile to load forever or else cause that app to freeze. YouTube will load the thumbnail and spinning icon but, if I switch to another app, even YouTube will be entirely frozen when I return to it. Likewise, if I attempt to record a video using any camera, the camera app will also freeze.

This does not appear to be related to audio processing as I can play audio streams fine, but if the file itself is a video file then I get the same result.

This is a new behavior not limited to a single app. The device is a galaxy tab s2 and developer mode is enabled. Clearly, whatever processes video streams in Android is bugging out on my device and needs to be restarted... but I would rather not fully restart my device as it is also suffering from a 'grey screen' problem where if I turn the screen off, there's a very high likelihood that turning the screen back on will result in it only displaying a solid grey screen, and it is very, very difficult to get it to display normally from there. Even straight from boot it will only display grey. I can still use the tablet by using an HDMI cable and using a tv as a screen, but I can only get the screen to display normally under some very arcane, specifc conditions: the tablet needs to have only about 20% battery life, and I need it to suddenly draw a lot of power all at once, such as by loading a power hungry app, while also attempting to turn the screen back on. Even this will only work once every 100 times. Yes, I know I need a new tablet. No, this one is no longer under warranty. I'd just like to get this one operational again, please.

Tldr: Is there a way I can restart the Android video engine without restarting the whole tablet?

PS: there are absolutely zero display artifacts, besides the grey screen issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the version of Android. If it is not the newest version, there may be a problem.
My phone, which before the major update a few months ago stopped playing Audio and lagged, and when i updated it all got fixed.

But another thing is, and i am not trying to scare, there may be a very bad software issue, or there could be a virus.